# No second level records on GridLookupEdit

Tags: c#, devexpress

I've created one grid lookup control and grid view. Both has the same datasource (list of entities with property of type list of other entity (for second level)). In case of grid view i have record and child records as expected. But for grid lookup edit there is no child records. Can't figure out why. 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GridLookUpEdit control cannot display master-detail relationships. As a work-around, you can use the [PopupContainerEdit](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/clsDevExpressXtraEditorsPopupContainerEdittopic) to display a standard XtraGrid within a pop-up window.

Comment: Well, PopupContainerEdit was actually first solution that i tried. But i am facing the problems with losing focus (i am using it as a text edit control to enter free text and to display filtered results in popup grid). So, seems there is no chance to implement it with GridLookupEdit. Thanks a lot!